# Enable rightMouseUp event for Flex Spark Application container

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

The spark Application container in Flex purportedly listens to the `rightMouseUp` and other right mouse button events. However, if press and release the right mouse button in the Flash player I only get the context menu.

How can I disable the context menu and make the application listen to right mouse button events instead?

Minimal example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
  mouseUp="onMouseUp(event)"
  rightMouseUp="onRightMouseUp(event)"
>
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.controls.Alert;

      private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
          Alert.show('left mouse up');
      }

      private function onRightMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
          Alert.show('right mouse up');
      }

    ]]>
  </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add higher vesrion of swf. 
 like: `-swf-version=20` in flex compiler in additional compiler arguments.

Here is the list of swf version with flash player version.

[SWF Version](http://sleepydesign.blogspot.in/2012/04/flash-swf-version-meaning.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't help, sorry. In Chrome on Linux I still get the Flashplayer context menu on right click, showing version 17.0.0.134.

Comment: You can remove context menu using `this.stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;`

Comment: Which swf version you are using?

Comment: `this.stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;` doesn't compile.  `import mx.core.FlexGlobals;FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.showDefaultContextMenu=false;` compiles, but now there is another context menu with 'Zoom In' as its first item and even the left mouse button event isn' t listened to any more. I used `-swf-version=20` as recommended. FlashPlayer version is 17.0.0.134 .

Comment: I didn't check in linux because i don't have. But it's working well in windows with firefox and chrome browser.